# How to change nav menu hover to click in Wordpress admin?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm changing the Wordpress admin menu so instead of a menu item's submenu opening to the right on hover, it opens with a dropdown beneath the parent item instead. I have made all the necessary CSS changes for this to work, except it still opens with cursor hover only, and won't stay open either.

I need to change the admin menu dropdown to open on click instead of hover.

Can someone please advise any javascript needed here? - or CSS if appropriate?

Many thanks

Example code from one menu item:

```
<li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-appearance menu-top-last" id="menu-appearance">
<a href="nav-menus.php" class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-appearance menu-top-last" aria-haspopup="true">
    <div class="wp-menu-arrow">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wp-menu-image dashicons-before dashicons-admin-appearance"><br></div>
    <div class="wp-menu-name">Appearance</div>
</a>
<ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap" style="">
    <li class="wp-submenu-head ws-nmh-is-new-menu" aria-hidden="true">Appearance
        <span class="ws-nmh-new-menu-flag" data-nmh-menu-url="themes.php"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="wp-first-item">
        <a href="nav-menus.php" class="wp-first-item">Menus</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="themes.php?page=update-theme-options">Theme Options</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="themes.php?page=import-theme-options">Import Theme Options</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="themes.php?page=export-theme-options">Export Theme Options</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a href="themes.php">Themes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hide-if-no-customize">
        <a href="customize.php?return=%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Dwpda_vertical_menu_themes" class="hide-if-no-customize">Customise</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="widgets.php">Widgets</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Custom CSS over and above Wordpress existing CSS:

```
.wp-menu-arrow {
    display: block !important;
}
#adminmenu li.wp-has-submenu .wp-menu-arrow div::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
#adminmenu .wp-has-submenu .wp-menu-arrow div::before {
    content: "\f345";
    color: #adb5bd;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    top: 13px;
    font-family: dashicons;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
#adminmenu li.wp-has-submenu.opensub .wp-menu-arrow div::before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #FFF;
}
#adminmenu .wp-submenu.wp-submenu-wrap {
    display:block;
}
#adminmenu .opensub .wp-submenu, #adminmenu .wp-menu-open .wp-submenu {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#adminmenu .wp-submenu {
    margin-left: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
#adminmenu .wp-not-current-submenu .wp-submenu, .folded #adminmenu .wp-has-current-submenu .wp-submenu {
    min-width: 220px;
    width: auto;
}
#adminmenu .wp-submenu .wp-submenu-head {
    padding: 20px 20px 10px;
}
```

Comment: you can use jquery toggle on click button

Comment: Thanks. Would you know any code I could use to do this? - perhaps so I can put into a custom plugin?...(I'm a newbie with that stuff)

Comment: my this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70703691/wp-floating-submenu-in-dashboard-sidebar-menu/70716667#70716667