# wp floating submenu in dashboard sidebar menu

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i successfully done making the menu name to be collapsed on click , but i have a problem with the floating submenu that appears on hover on menu name ,
i need to make this floating submenu to be open not floating on hover after i click on menu name,

i found this code for the adminmenu

```
    $submenu_items = array();
    if ( ! empty( $submenu[ $item[2] ] ) ) {
        $class[]       = 'wp-has-submenu';
        $submenu_items = $submenu[ $item[2] ];
    }

    if ( ( $parent_file && $item[2] === $parent_file ) || ( empty( $typenow ) && $self === $item[2] ) ) {
        if ( ! empty( $submenu_items ) ) {
            $class[] = 'wp-has-current-submenu wp-menu-open';
        } else {
            $class[]          = 'current';
            $aria_attributes .= 'aria-current="page"';
        }
    } else {
        $class[] = 'wp-not-current-submenu';
        if ( ! empty( $submenu_items ) ) {
            $aria_attributes .= 'aria-haspopup="true"';
        }
    }
```

and this js code that i think it responsible for this but i don't know exactly which one

```
/**
 * Handles the `aria-haspopup` attribute on the current menu item when it has a submenu.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @return {void}
 */
function currentMenuItemHasPopup() {
    var $current = $( 'a.wp-has-current-submenu' );

    if ( 'folded' === menuState ) {
        // When folded or auto-folded and not responsive view, the current menu item does have a fly-out sub-menu.
        $current.attr( 'aria-haspopup', 'true' );
    } else {
        // When expanded or in responsive view, reset aria-haspopup.
        $current.attr( 'aria-haspopup', 'false' );
    }
}

$document.on( 'wp-menu-state-set wp-collapse-menu wp-responsive-activate wp-responsive-deactivate', currentMenuItemHasPopup );

/**
 * Ensures an admin submenu is within the visual viewport.
 *
 * @since 4.1.0
 *
 * @param {jQuery} $menuItem The parent menu item containing the submenu.
 *
 * @return {void}
 */
function adjustSubmenu( $menuItem ) {
    var bottomOffset, pageHeight, adjustment, theFold, menutop, wintop, maxtop,
        $submenu = $menuItem.find( '.wp-submenu' );

    menutop = $menuItem.offset().top;
    wintop = $window.scrollTop();
    maxtop = menutop - wintop - 30; // max = make the top of the sub almost touch admin bar.

    bottomOffset = menutop + $submenu.height() + 1; // Bottom offset of the menu.
    pageHeight = $wpwrap.height();                  // Height of the entire page.
    adjustment = 60 + bottomOffset - pageHeight;
    theFold = $window.height() + wintop - 50;       // The fold.

    if ( theFold < ( bottomOffset - adjustment ) ) {
        adjustment = bottomOffset - theFold;
    }

    if ( adjustment > maxtop ) {
        adjustment = maxtop;
    }

    if ( adjustment > 1 ) {
        $submenu.css( 'margin-top', '-' + adjustment + 'px' );
    } else {
        $submenu.css( 'margin-top', '' );
    }
}

if ( 'ontouchstart' in window || /IEMobile\/[1-9]/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { // Touch screen device.
    // iOS Safari works with touchstart, the rest work with click.
    mobileEvent = isIOS ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

    /**
     * Closes any open submenus when touch/click is not on the menu.
     *
     * @param {Event} e The event object.
     *
     * @return {void}
     */
    $body.on( mobileEvent+'.wp-mobile-hover', function(e) {
        if ( $adminmenu.data('wp-responsive') ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! $( e.target ).closest( '#adminmenu' ).length ) {
            $adminmenu.find( 'li.opensub' ).removeClass( 'opensub' );
        }
    });

    /**
     * Handles the opening or closing the submenu based on the mobile click|touch event.
     *
     * @param {Event} event The event object.
     *
     * @return {void}
     */
    $adminmenu.find( 'a.wp-has-submenu' ).on( mobileEvent + '.wp-mobile-hover', function( event ) {
        var $menuItem = $(this).parent();

        if ( $adminmenu.data( 'wp-responsive' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Show the sub instead of following the link if:
         *  - the submenu is not open.
         *  - the submenu is not shown inline or the menu is not folded.
         */
        if ( ! $menuItem.hasClass( 'opensub' ) && ( ! $menuItem.hasClass( 'wp-menu-open' ) || $menuItem.width() < 40 ) ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            adjustSubmenu( $menuItem );
            $adminmenu.find( 'li.opensub' ).removeClass( 'opensub' );
            $menuItem.addClass('opensub');
        }
    });
}

if ( ! isIOS && ! isAndroid ) {
    $adminmenu.find( 'li.wp-has-submenu' ).hoverIntent({

        /**
         * Opens the submenu when hovered over the menu item for desktops.
         *
         * @return {void}
         */
        over: function() {
            var $menuItem = $( this ),
                $submenu = $menuItem.find( '.wp-submenu' ),
                top = parseInt( $submenu.css( 'top' ), 10 );

            if ( isNaN( top ) || top > -5 ) { // The submenu is visible.
                return;
            }

            if ( $adminmenu.data( 'wp-responsive' ) ) {
                // The menu is in responsive mode, bail.
                return;
            }

            adjustSubmenu( $menuItem );
            $adminmenu.find( 'li.opensub' ).removeClass( 'opensub' );
            $menuItem.addClass( 'opensub' );
        },

        /**
         * Closes the submenu when no longer hovering the menu item.
         *
         * @return {void}
         */
        out: function(){
            if ( $adminmenu.data( 'wp-responsive' ) ) {
                // The menu is in responsive mode, bail.
                return;
            }

            $( this ).removeClass( 'opensub' ).find( '.wp-submenu' ).css( 'margin-top', '' );
        },
        timeout: 200,
        sensitivity: 7,
        interval: 90
    });

    /**
     * Opens the submenu on when focused on the menu item.
     *
     * @param {Event} event The event object.
     *
     * @return {void}
     */
    $adminmenu.on( 'focus.adminmenu', '.wp-submenu a', function( event ) {
        if ( $adminmenu.data( 'wp-responsive' ) ) {
            // The menu is in responsive mode, bail.
            return;
        }

        $( event.target ).closest( 'li.menu-top' ).addClass( 'opensub' );

        /**
         * Closes the submenu on blur from the menu item.
         *
         * @param {Event} event The event object.
         *
         * @return {void}
         */
    }).on( 'blur.adminmenu', '.wp-submenu a', function( event ) {
        if ( $adminmenu.data( 'wp-responsive' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $( event.target ).closest( 'li.menu-top' ).removeClass( 'opensub' );

        /**
         * Adjusts the size for the submenu.
         *
         * @return {void}
         */
    }).find( 'li.wp-has-submenu.wp-not-current-submenu' ).on( 'focusin.adminmenu', function() {
        adjustSubmenu( $( this ) );
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I successfully solved it and done making the requirement in an easy way

```
// style for removing floating submenu and make it inside sidbbar

$('#adminmenu .wp-not-current-submenu .wp-submenu').append(`<style>
   #adminmenu .wp-not-current-submenu .wp-submenu {
       position: relative;
       min-width:auto;
       left:auto;
       top: auto;
       box-shadow:none;
       display:none;
    }
    </style>`);
```

```
// this Code to make menu show/ hide the submenu on click

$('#adminmenu > li.wp-has-submenu').click(function(e) {  
        
        // element to toggle
        var $el = $('ul',this); 

        // after clicking any other menu item slide up other elements
        $('#adminmenu > li.wp-has-submenu > ul').not($el).slideUp(); 

        // toggle element
        $el.stop(true, true).slideToggle(400); 
        return false;
    });

    // stop events from bubbling from sub menu clicks
    $('#adminmenu > li.wp-has-submenu > ul > li').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); 
    });
```

this my final result [image]